# What is the reason for the error in the int class in the code I've written?

Tags: discord.py

What is causing the error in the init class?
I'm trying to declare a class, but I'm not sure what to do.
(It is discord.ext)
my code is:

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
#Client = command_prefix

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')

async def on_message(message):

@commands.Bot(name="<<kick", pass_context= True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def _kick(ctx, *, username: discord.Member, reason=None):
    await user_name.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(str(user_name) + '\n```User was kick!```')
        
        

    
client.run(token)
````

error is
`TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'command_prefix'`

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

You have
`@commands.Bot(name="<<kick", pass_context= True)` which should be `@client.command(name="kick", pass_context= True)` you also had an indent error (`async def on_message(message):`) which usually comes at the end of your commands.  ```` await ctx.send(str(user_name) + '\n```User was kick!```') ```` here you refer to user_name instead of username, which you defined in the function.

I tested the code and this is what it should look like when fixed:

````py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"


# Client = command_prefix

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')


@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')


@client.command(name="kick", pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def _kick(ctx, *, username: discord.Member, reason=None):
    await username.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(str(username) + '\n```User was kick!```')


client.run(token)
````